# Showing through-hole pads in printouts with Altium

Tags: altium

In Altium (at least in version 14) when I create a PDF I don't see the pads.  I generally create outjobs to produce PDFs of the PCB that have different copper layers on each page, essentially a PDF of the Gerbers.  But through-hole pads which are multilayer don't appear on the top or bottom layers.

This is an example of what I mean.  Here is what the PCB looks like in the layout editor:

[image]

And this is is what the PDF looks like, top and bottom:

[image][image]

I would like the option to show the pads so I can confirm connectivity, etc. without needing to use a Gerber viewer.  I can change the color of the 'Multi-Layer' layer in the PCB Printout Properties in the Preferences window, e.g. to red, as shown below, but then the pad appears red on all layers, instead of blue on the bottom layer and red on the top layer.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, my guess is the pads do show up on the "multi-layer" page of the PDF?

Comment: By default the mutlilayer color is white so it doesn't appear, but if I set the color, yes it does appear.  The problem is that it's always the same color, so if I include Multi-layer on bot top and bottom sheets, those parts appear the same color on both sheets.

Comment: I am not near my Altium computer but I recognize your problem and suggest that you adjust the drawing order of the layers.

Comment: I tried a number of variations with different layer order, but haven't been able to fix it.